# C function runs on Mac OS X 10.11 or earlier or on Windows, but crashes in Mac OS X 10.12

Tags: c++, assembly, macos-sierra

I have a dynamically loadable bundle on Mac OS X and it crashes on Mac OS X Sierra. It works fine on earlier Mac OS X versions (at least on 64-bit) and also (this is a cross-platform plug-in and this code is shared) on Windows, both 32- and 64-bit. The bundle is compiled on Mac OS X 10.11 with `clang` in universal mode without optimizations against 10.11 SDK; the minimal OS version was set first to 10.4, then to 10.11 without any effect.

It crashes in a rather simple function. I don't have access to a computer with Sierra, so all I have is a crash log, the binary that crashes, and the source. I'm trying to read the assembly dump to understand what might be wrong. So far everything seems to be OK (with some redundant operations, but no error), but I'm not fluent with assembly. Below are the relevant parts:

The crash log:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000140009f3cabc
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
...
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 ... 0x0000000109f2825b Do_GetString2(unsigned char, unsigned long, unsigned short*) + 171
...
Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fcb95adc528  rcx: 0x0000140009f3cabc  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000082  rsi: 0x0000000000000100  rbp: 0x00007fff5b5f5f10  rsp: 0x00007fff5b5f5f10
   r8: 0x00000000000014c0   r9: 0x0000000000000001  r10: 0x0000000106c823fc  r11: 0x0000000106c82400
  r12: 0x0000000000000082  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007fcb95adc552  r15: 0xffffffffffffffff
  rip: 0x0000000109f2825b  rfl: 0x0000000000010287  cr2: 0x0000140009f3cabc
```

The `Do_GetString2` is a simple function that copies a few short ASCII strings into wider UTF-16 strings:

```
static void
Do_GetString2(uint8_t type, uint64_t limit, uint16_t *target)
{
    const char *source; uint64_t i;

    switch (type) {
        case 128 : source = strings[0]; break;
        case 129 : source = strings[1]; break;
        case 131 : source = strings[2]; break;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < limit && source[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        target[i] = source[i];
}
```

`strings` is like that:

```
static const char* strings[] = {
    "... A ...",
    "... B ...",
    "... C ..."
};
```

The assembly code is below. The crashing address, as far as I undersand, is (+171) `000000000000125b`, which  means it crashes when it tries to read `source[i]`, the very first character (`i` is `0`). The `type` parameter is `131`, the `limit` is `256` (`0x100`). (I could be wrong here, as I said, I'm not that familiar with assembly.) This is probably the very first call to the library.

```
__ZL13Do_GetString2hmPt:
00000000000011b0    pushq   %rbp
00000000000011b1    movq    %rsp, %rbp
00000000000011b4    movb    %dil, %al
00000000000011b7    movb    %al, -0x1(%rbp)
00000000000011ba    movq    %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
00000000000011be    movq    %rdx, -0x18(%rbp)
00000000000011c2    movzbl  -0x1(%rbp), %edi
00000000000011c6    movl    %edi, %ecx
00000000000011c8    subl    $0x80, %ecx
00000000000011ce    movl    %edi, -0x2c(%rbp)
00000000000011d1    movl    %ecx, -0x30(%rbp)
00000000000011d4    je  0x121b
00000000000011da    jmp 0x11df
00000000000011df    movl    -0x2c(%rbp), %eax
00000000000011e2    subl    $0x81, %eax
00000000000011e7    movl    %eax, -0x34(%rbp)
00000000000011ea    je  0x122b
00000000000011f0    jmp 0x11f5
00000000000011f5    movl    -0x2c(%rbp), %eax
00000000000011f8    subl    $0x83, %eax
00000000000011fd    movl    %eax, -0x38(%rbp)
0000000000001200    jne 0x1236
0000000000001206    jmp 0x120b
000000000000120b    movq    __ZL14plugin_strings(%rip), %rax ## plugin_strings
0000000000001212    movq    %rax, -0x20(%rbp)
0000000000001216    jmp 0x1236
000000000000121b    movq    0x15406(%rip), %rax
0000000000001222    movq    %rax, -0x20(%rbp)
0000000000001226    jmp 0x1236
000000000000122b    movq    0x153fe(%rip), %rax
0000000000001232    movq    %rax, -0x20(%rbp)
0000000000001236    movq    $0x0, -0x28(%rbp)
000000000000123e    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000000001240    movb    %al, %cl
0000000000001242    movq    -0x28(%rbp), %rdx
0000000000001246    cmpq    -0x10(%rbp), %rdx
000000000000124a    movb    %cl, -0x39(%rbp)
000000000000124d    jae 0x126d
0000000000001253    movq    -0x28(%rbp), %rax
0000000000001257    movq    -0x20(%rbp), %rcx
000000000000125b    movsbl  (%rcx,%rax), %edx  # CRASHES HERE
000000000000125f    cmpl    $0x0, %edx
0000000000001265    setne   %sil
0000000000001269    movb    %sil, -0x39(%rbp)
000000000000126d    movb    -0x39(%rbp), %al
0000000000001270    testb   $0x1, %al
0000000000001272    jne 0x127d
0000000000001278    jmp 0x12ad
000000000000127d    movq    -0x28(%rbp), %rax
0000000000001281    movq    -0x20(%rbp), %rcx
0000000000001285    movb    (%rcx,%rax), %dl
0000000000001288    movsbl  %dl, %esi
000000000000128b    movw    %si, %di
000000000000128e    movq    -0x28(%rbp), %rax
0000000000001292    movq    -0x18(%rbp), %rcx
0000000000001296    movw    %di, (%rcx,%rax,2)
000000000000129a    movq    -0x28(%rbp), %rax
000000000000129e    addq    $0x1, %rax
00000000000012a4    movq    %rax, -0x28(%rbp)
00000000000012a8    jmp 0x123e
00000000000012ad    popq    %rbp
00000000000012ae    retq
00000000000012af    nop
```

Does anyone see any error here? What could I try to debug this crash? This is a GUI application, so I'm not sure I can debug it with gdb or something like that over SSH.

Comment: If `type` is not 128, 129, 131 then where does `source` get initialized?

Comment: With the 64-bit ABI parameters are passed in registers first. _RDI_, _RSI_, _RDX_  are the first 3 parameters (in order). It appears _RDI_ = `type` = 0x82 . 0x82 is the value 130 which you don't have in the case statement. Your loop then proceeds to use `source` which isn't initialized to anything

Comment: See http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/06-Debugging_A_Running_Process.php for how to use `gdb` to debug a running process. Have the user start the GUI application, get its PID with `ps` or Activity Monitor, then attach to the PID.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: This doesn't happen in this library: the type is always one of these constants. But I agree I should've written it not to do anything in this case. Do you think this is relevant here? Oh, I see; this is probably it. I'll get back to testing and if it's OK and you turn the comment into a reply, I'll accept it.

Comment: I have to disagree with you. If that code snippet is correct then the type passed in was 130 (0x82). As well it appears that NULL (0x0000) was passed in as `target`. You'd also have failure to assign to `target` if that is the case and that would crash as well. From what I see this function was called with `type` as 130, `limit` as 256, and `target` was _NULL_. So issues are `source` was probably not initialized and `target` was a NULL pointer.

Comment: I´m not supposed to handle an unlisted `type`, so I just do nothing if this happens. I just didn't expect to get it and was sloppy here. The fix seems to work though. `target` being `NULL` is up to the caller here.

Comment: Actually looking at the assembler code `target` may not have been _NULL_  when the function was first entered (I misread part of the assembly code). If you put assertions in your code you could test for things like `target` being _NULL_ etc.